# Is this correct to check Game Center Achievement's Progress?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, xcode4, game-center

I want my app to check if the achievements are completed or not and I wrote the next:

```
-(void)checkAchievements{
    NSString* identifier = NULL;
    double percentComplete = 0;
    if (self.SavedScore >= 100) {
        identifier = kAchivement100Taps;
        percentComplete = 100.0;
    }

    if (self.SavedScore >= 500) {
            identifier = kAchivement500Taps;
            percentComplete = 100.0;
    }

    [...more similar achievements...]

    if(identifier!= NULL){
        [self.gameCenterManager submitAchievement: identifier percentComplete: percentComplete];
    }
}
```

Is this method correct?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is the right way to check if an achievement is complete:

```
- (void) loadAchievements
{
    [GKAchievement loadAchievementsWithCompletionHandler:^(NSArray *achievements, NSError *error)
        {
            if (error == nil)
            {
                for (GKAchievement* achievement in achievements)
                    GKAchievement *gkAchmt = [[[GKAchievement alloc] initWithIdentifier: achievement.achievementId] autorelease];

                    if (gkAchmt.isCompleted) {
                        // This achievement is achieved.
                    }

            }
        }];
}
```

So, if you have your achievements to sync in an array, you can do something like this:

```
for (Achievement *achievement in arrAchievementsToSync) {
    GKAchievement *gkAchmt = [[[GKAchievement alloc] initWithIdentifier: achievement.achievementId] autorelease];

    if (!gkAchmt.isCompleted) {
        [self submitAchievement:gkAchmt percentComplete:100.0f];
    }
}
```

Comment: @yeker3 but you are only submitting and not checking the progress. Your question was how to check Game Center achievement's progress right?

Comment: well yes, but I wanted to do both, I'm a bit lost on how to do that. Because my method only gives me one Achievement at a time. There is a button that saves the progress and when you tap on it, it should check if you won any more achievement since last save, and if you win more than one achievement before saving you only get the last one.

Comment: @yeker3 The method i mentioned iterates through all the achievements. So, if you have your achievements to sync in an array, you can do something like what I mentioned in the edit.

Comment: could you tell me how to do that please? (How to set the array)